# Different looping behaviors in Groovy

Tags: java, loops, groovy

Why do these two loops have different results? I thought they would both initialize all of the values in each array to 5 but only the second one works. Could someone explain why this is?

```
static main(args)
{
    double[][] x = new double[3][3]
    double[][] y = new double[3][3]

    for(row in x)
    {
        for(num in row)
        {
            num=5
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<y.size();i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<y[i].size();j++)
        {
            y[i][j]=5
        }
    }

    println "x: ${x}" 
    println "y: ${y}"
}
```

And here's the output

```
x: [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
y: [[5.0, 5.0, 5.0], [5.0, 5.0, 5.0], [5.0, 5.0, 5.0]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First pair of `for` loops does nothing and it is correct. 
`num` is a new variable in scope of inner `for`. It is a reference to the integer from table. When you assign it, it becomes a reference to value 5. Table cell does not change.

For a C programmer.

```
int five = 5;
int *num;
```

It is:

```
num = &five;
```

It is not:

```
*num = five;
```

Answer (score 2):

In the first loop you're changing a local variable that never updates what is in the array. `num` holds a copy of the data in the array element, but there's no reference back to the array entry, so changing it has no effect on the array.

This way is a little groovier than the old-style for-loop:

```
for (i in 0..x.length - 1) {
    for (j in 0..y.length - 1) {
        x[i][j] = 5
    }
}
```

or you can do without the `for`:

```
(i in 0 .. x.length - 1).each { i ->
    (j in 0 .. y.length - 1).each { j ->
        x[i][j] = 5
    }
}
```

Comment: And `​double[][]​ x = (0​..2).collect { [5] * 3 }​` is groovier too

Comment: Or `double[][] x = [ [5] * 3 ] * 3`

Comment: @tim_yates: those are much better, except for returning a ArrayList. i interpreted the requirement to be to return an array.

Comment: @NathanHughes  In both of those cases, x is a 2d double array :-)

Comment: @tim_yates: ok, i see now, in groovysh I can't put a type on the variable, I just evaluate the expression, so that wasn't what I was seeing.